# Android Apk is Not Being Published on Google Play

Tags: android, certificate, apk, uploading

I have developed and android Application and export as APK file to publish this on google play .Problem is that when i try to upload an apk file there gernerated an error  of
`"The certificate that signed this apk is not valid until the future. Create a new certificate.`"

And Apk dnt be  uploaded please any one help me or tell me where will be the issue i have exported it as apk file its certificate information as required in eclips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably some issue with the certificate. The certificate guide lets you create a certificate valid for many years, which it suggests to make at leat 25. Double check if you made sure that is correct.

OR

Try moving your system time back one day and sign your app, should be a fair workaround :)

Comment: Yes Worked by taking time to back one day.Will u please describe what is the issue with time and google server ? please

Comment: Yes, there is problem with Google Servers - their time is little off

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a valid certificate. See the following link for signing your app for a release:

[App signing & releasemode](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode)

Comment: But I am Exporting apk Formally from eclips as i exported two or more application and they uploaded fine on google play

Comment: How long ago did you upload them? Are you using the same certificate?

Comment: NO I am Using Different Alias

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set the time in your machine wrong. Maybe a time ahead of the google servers.

Check this out,

[time set 3 hours ahead in my windows](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/12175-cant-upload-apk-android-market.html)

[This also proves it](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/2MEmWsP3j2E)